# Network request failed : Unhandled promise rejection, after react-native upgradation to 0.52

Tags: git, api, react-native

My login code was working properly when I was using `react-native-0.41.2` and `react-15.4.2`. Now I have upgraded `react-native to 0.52` and `react 0.16.2`. But now API is not giving any response when I tried to login into the app.
I also tried to make some changes in Info.plist file keys but it didn't work. Please provide me any suggestion for it.

[image]

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = '';
    var pass = '';
    user = this.state.username;
    pass = this.state.password;
    this.authenticate(user, pass);
    return;
  }
  async authenticate(username, password) {
    let _this = this;
    Api.login(username, password)
    .then(async response => {await response.json()})
    .then(async response => {
      //My code
    });
 }
 render() {
  let { username, password } = this.state;
  return (
       <View >
        <TextField
          label='username'
          value={username}
          autoCapitalize= 'none'
          onChangeText={ (username) => this.setState({ username }) }
        />
        <TextField
          label='password'
          value={password}
          secureTextEntry autoCapitalize= 'none'
          onChangeText={ (password) => this.setState({ password }) }
          style={{marginBottom: 10}}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButtons} onPress={(e) => 
        this.login(e)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Login </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
   );
 }
}
```

My api code -

```
login(username, password) {
let url = '/api/sessions';
return fetch(BASE_URL + url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user: {
      email: username,
      password: password
    }
  })
});}
```

Comment: It might be cause of you using **fetch**
For good idea, you should post the source code or provide some clue it will easily for everyone to answer straight to your question dear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let using **Catch** to catch the execption in your request.
Seem your code OK, let try to find out the problem in catch and make sure your request **URL** is in correct path request.

For example:

```
fetch('... Your URL')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Hope it will help for some idea...

Comment: I tried but still, error exists. The same code was working before up-gradation of react-native and all the packages

Comment: Did u know how to debug and console the error?
You can try to debug on the simulator to find out what it **catch**

Comment: the debugger is not working in a catch. No catch statement execution happened

Comment: Did u check your API request working fine?

Comment: how to check it ?

Comment: U can test on PostMan for post request and it work fine or not???